# How to list domains in virsh?

Tags: virtual-machine

`virsh list` returns an empty list but the gui `virt-manager` has 2 defined QEMU/KVM virtual machines. How come `virsh list` doesn't list anythng ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `virsh list` command only runs things *running*.

If you want things defined but not running then

```
virsh list --all
```

And remember each type of namespace is distinct so you may need `--connect` as well

e.g.

```
$ virsh -c lxc:/// list      
 Id    Name                           State
----------------------------------------------------


$ virsh -c lxc:/// list --all
 Id    Name                           State
----------------------------------------------------
 -     helloworld                     shut off

$ virsh -c qemu:///system list
 Id    Name                           State
----------------------------------------------------
 37    fedora24                       running

$ virsh -c qemu:///system list --all
 Id    Name                           State
----------------------------------------------------
 37    fedora24                       running
 -     docker                         shut off
 -     kali                           shut off
 -     test1                          shut off
```

Comment: nice I also have a network defined but it doesn't appear in the list (i want to know the name I have to undefine). How could I list it ? edit : nvm it's `net-list`

Comment: `virsh net-list --all`.    `virsh help` gives a list of all the commands, so things like `virsh help | grep network`  produces a list of network related commands; `virsh net-list` was one of them, and (just as with `virsh list`) you need `--all` to show inactive networks as well.